# Rolling.sum() with all previous occurrences?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been looking through the .rolling documentation and it seems like you need to provide a window, but all I would like to do is just sum all previous occurrences of a certain column in order of `occurs`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'person':['john','mike','john','mike','john','mike','john','mike','john','mike'],
                   'star':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   'occurs':[1001,1001,1002,1002,1003,1003,1004,1004,1005,1005],
                    })
```

[image]

Here is what I tried, this is not the correct solution.

```
df['b'] = df.groupby('person')['star'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2).sum().shift())
```

Desired Result:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'person':['john','mike','john','mike','john','mike','john','mike','john','mike'],
                          'star':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                          'occurs':[1001,1001,1002,1002,1003,1003,1004,1004,1005,1005],
                          'b':[None,None,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
                          })
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Instead of the `rolling` window you can use `cumsum()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'person':['john','mike','john','mike','john','mike','john','mike','john','mike'],
                   'star':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   'occurs':[1001,1001,1002,1002,1003,1003,1004,1004,1005,1005],
                    })

df['b'] = df.groupby('person')['star'].cumsum() - 1
df.loc[df['b'] == 0, 'b'] = np.nan
df
```

The `-1` and the `df.loc[df['b'] == 0, 'b'] = np.nan` is just to get the exact same result that you want.

Comment: just a note: i wouldn't call the column name `cumsum` because it will be shadowed by the dataframe method `cumsum`

Comment: changed the column name from `cumsum` to `b` to avoid that problem and keep it consistent with the desired output. thanks!